# Prove that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$ using algebraic manipulations of derivatives?

Tags: limits, trigonometry, derivatives, alternative-proof

I can prove that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos(x)-1}x=0$ since

$$\sin^2(x)=1-\cos^2(x)$$

$$\implies2\sin'(x)\sin(x)=-2\cos'(x)\cos(x)$$

$$\sin'(x)\sin(x)=-\cos'(x)\cos(x)$$

at $x=0$, we have

$$0=-\cos'(0)$$

Thus, $\cos'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos(x)-1}x=0$.

Can one produce the same result for the famous $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}x=1$ by manipulating derivatives?

Particularly, can we calculate $\sin'(0)$ without first showing that $\sin'(x)=\cos(x)$?

---

Edit:

As has been shown, we need more than just trig identities to prove this, since trig identities work regardless of the radian/degrees while the limit does not.  So consider the following information:

$$0\le\frac{\sin(x+t)-\sin(x)}t\le\cos(x)\ \forall\ x\in(0,\frac\pi2),\ t\in\left(0,\frac\pi2-x\right)$$

The last inequality proven geometrically in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8846/proofs-without-words/8932#8932).

Thus, we get

$$0\le\sin'(0)\le\cos(0)$$

As of yet, I'm unsure what other information should be required, mainly how to deal with the units issue.

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)-\sin(0)}{x}=\sin'(0)=\cos(0)=1$?

Comment: @A.G. Yes, but you may not use the knowledge that $\sin'(x)=\cos(x)$, just as I have not used $\cos'(x)=-\sin(x)$.

Comment: How do you know that $\sin^{\prime}=\cos$ ? Usually this is derived as a consequence of the limit in your title.

Comment: @SimpleArt How do you propose we prove that $\sin'(0)$ is finite, then? Or at least that $\lim_{x\to0}\sin'(x)\sin(x)=0$?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Well, suppose I don't know that $\lim\frac{\sin x}x=1$, since it is what we are trying to find and consequently I don't know that $\sin'=\cos$.  So in short, I don't know that fact.

Comment: @Arthur By looking at a graph, it stands to good reason that one can assume $\sin'(x)$ is a bounded function.

Comment: @SimpleArt How would you know from the graph that nothing funny happens around $x=10^{-\text{Graham's number}}$?

Comment: Its not clear what you are taking as your starting point, you need to begin with some limits as given. Usually the limit in the title is proved by the squeeze and is the cornerstone for many further limits.

Comment: @Arthur You could look at [this answer](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8846/proofs-without-words/8932#8932) to get an approximate understanding of $\sin'$.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus I take as a starting point all derivative rules and trig identities and I want to prove this by "solving" for $\sin'(0)$.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus From looking at the question, I'd say it's pretty clear he's assumed that 1) $\sin'$ exists and is bounded near $0$, and that 2)  normal differentiation rules, specifically the chain rule, applies.

Comment: @Arthur If you take a good look at that image, you will notice that for $0<x<\pi/2,0<t<\pi/2-x$, we have the following bounds:$$0\le\frac{\sin(x+t)-\sin(x)}t\le\cos(x)$$

Comment: If all you are given is that $s(x)$ and $c(x)$ are functions which satisfy $s(x)^2+c(x)^2 = 1$ for all real $x$ and $s(0) = 0$ and $c(0) = 1$, then both [$s(x) = \sin(x)$, $c(x) = \cos(x)$] and [$s(x) = -\sin(x)$, $c(x) = \cos(x)$] are solutions. So it won't be possible to decide whether  $s'(0) = 1$ or $s'(0) = -1$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 I do not think that is a big problem, please see the comment above yours.

Comment: I don't know if you can find the limit by solving $\sin'(0)$, but you could find it if you can prove the following inequality : $\sin x \leq x \leq \tan x$, $x \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$, which might be something you would be okay with.

Comment: @Desura That is clearly one of the normal ways of doing the problem, and I want to tackle this with derivative specifically.  If you are interested in such "regular" proofs, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1?rq=1).

Comment: What can we assume about sin(x)? In calculus the sine-function is defined as the inverse of an integral which has been shown not to be reducables to simple powers. This is Int(1/sqrt(1-t^2),(t,0,x)) =(def)= arcsin(x). For small x we can replace the sqrt by 1 and obtain int ~= x. Taking now the sine of the approximate equation we get sin(x) ~= sin(arcsin(x))== x which proves the relation in question.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze I would probably define it via the unit circle, which is where I get the inequality $0\le\frac{\sin(x+t)-\sin(x)}t\le\cos(x)$ in the comments above and all the trig identities (including the one I used in my question)

Comment: @Simple Art: I understand. I deliberately wanted to take a purely arithmetic - i.e. non-geometric - approach as an alternative. Of course the arcsin is - as the word says - the arc ON the unit circle from the point (1,0) to the point (cos(t), sin(t)).

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze Personally though, I do not believe that to be the standard definition of $\sin$.  But whatever floats your boat I guess.

Comment: @SimpleArt: The point of my comment was that using only the information $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x) = 1$, $\sin(0) = 0$, $\cos(0) = 1$ and manipulating derivatives will not be enough to determine $\sin'(0)$. If you have other assumptions about $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$, then you might be able to prove $\sin'(0) = 1$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Yes, I can see that now.  Thank you for your interesting contributions :D

Comment: @Simple Art: At least that's how I learned it ages ago in my calculus course where a hierarchy of functions was built in this manner: step 1 all powers can be intergrated easily, except 1/x. This integral is then defined as the logarithm. It inverse is the exponential function. Next came algebraic functions like the one sqrt above etc. Of course you can define sin(x) otherwise, e.g. via the infinite product. Then your relation is trivial.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it is possible to derive that $\sin'(0)=1$ using only "trigonometric identities", due to the fact that trigonometric identities (at least what I call trigonometric identities - see (*)) are blind with respect to the essential fact that makes $\frac{\sin(x)}{x} \to 1$, which is, informally speaking, the measurement by "radians".

What we can do using only trigonometric identities is derive the fact that $\sin'(x)=\sin'(0) \cos(x)$ and $\cos'(x)=-\sin'(0)\sin(x)$. For the first, consider the identity
$$\sin(x+y)=\sin(x)\cos(y) +\sin(y)\cos(x).$$
Differentiating with respect to $y$, we get
$$\sin'(x+y)=\sin(x)\cos'(y)+\sin'(y)\cos(x).$$
Evaluating at $y=0$,
$$\sin'(x)=\sin(x)\cos'(0)+\sin'(0)\cos(x)$$
$$\therefore \sin'(x)=\sin'(0)\cos(x),$$
since you concluded that $\cos'(0)=0$. Analogously, using the identity for $\cos(x+y)$, one reaches the other formula.

(*) The question is quite unclear. Using only "trigonometry", we are left with a fair amount of freedom on the functions $\sin$, $\cos$ as real functions (essentially, changing $\sin(x)$ to $\sin(kx)$ for some constant $k \neq 0$ does not change trigonometry, which is what we perceive in practice as a "change of units" on the angles. And this amounts to changing $\sin'(0)$ as well, by the same factor). More explicitly with respect to the question, I consider a "trigonometric identity" to entail (not iff) that it is invariant under changing the functions $\sin(x)$, $\cos(x)$ by $\sin(k x)$, $\cos(kx)$. As such, it is thus impossible to prove that $\sin'(0)=1$ using only "trigonometric identities", because there is always a factor on the derivative which can come from the constant $k$.

Comment: Hm, you make very good points at the end.  It comes to be that regardless of units, I can derive $\cos'(0)=0$, but not for $\sin'(0)$.  I'll think about that if I can figure out any ways to improve the question.

Answer (score 1):

We can easily see that the trigonometric relations

$$\sin (0)=0, \cos (0)=1, \sin ^2(x)+\cos ^2(x)=1$$

are not sufficient to prove

$$\lim_{x\to0}{\sin(x)\over x} = 1$$

Indeed, define two functions

$$\text{sen}(x)=\sin (a x), \text{ces}(x)=\cos (a x)$$

These satisfy the conditions above but

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \, \frac{\text{sen}(x)}{x}=a$$

which obviously need not be unity.

Comment: No worries about $\LaTeX$, it won't stop me from fixing it up :D